# iOS StreamStatus always returns NSStreamStatusOpen

Tags: ios, inputstream, outputstream, nsstream

Just had a question regarding the streamStatus of a NSStream. In my application I have an input stream and an output stream that work well in sending and receiving data. Earlier, however, I've noticed that should the server go down I wasn't receiving any notification on the client side that the connection broke. After several weeks of trying to research this and implementing various tests I found that none of them provided me with a proper response to an improper server disconnect or crash. I then created a timer that fired off every 5 seconds and called a function that checked the streamStatus. Upon disconnecting the server by disabling the LAN connection I noticed the client still registering as being connected. When I started to debug the client I noticed that streamStatus always returned `NSStreamStatusOpen` on both my input and output streams.

Is there something that I am missing on my end that I am not doing? I have attached below a small snippet of how I am calling and receiving the streamStatus.

Initializing the timer (Called after a successful connection):

```
connectionTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(CheckStream) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Checking the streams:

```
- (void)CheckStream
{
    NSStreamStatus status = [input streamStatus];

    if(status == NSStreamStatusClosed || status == NSStreamStatusError)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %d", status);
    }

    status = [output streamStatus];

    if(status == NSStreamStatusClosed || status == NSStreamStatusError)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %d", status);
    }
}
```

Comment: i am having a similar problem. if i call streamstatus i Always get connection open, but never "writing" even if i AM indeed writing. have an idea how to solve this?